# Create tensorflow dataset of images & labels from simple python lists

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have been trying to use various inspirations - notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590363/create-tensorflow-dataset-from-image-local-directory) - to create a labelled dataset of images to pass to [model.fit()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54635190).

My code appears equivalent to that given in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54635190) to that question... with a slightly different `_parse_function()` compared to the OP of the question:

```
def load_image( path, label ):
  file_contents = tf.io.read_file( path )
  image = tf.image.decode_image( file_contents )
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype( image, tf.float32 )
  return image, label
```

I can test this function independently within python command line, e.g. with `image, label = load_image( "tiger.jpg", "Tiger" )` and end up with a label of `"Tiger"` and an `image[0][0]` that corresponds correctly to the top-left pixel of the image:

```
>>> image[0][0]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.37254903, 0.5529412 , 0.854902  ], dtype=float32)>
```

Likewise, if I try `print( image[ 0 ][ 0 ]` from within my program, I get:

```
tf.Tensor([0.37254903 0.5529412  0.854902  ], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

I'm new to python, so I'm hoping these are just equivalent variations on a theme, but either way, when I pass everything through to `model.fit()` in my program, I end up with:

```
 ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.
```

No variation on any theme has taken me beyond this point. I have eliminated all pipeline operations from the dataset (e.g. no `.shuffle()`, no `.repeat()`, no `.batch()`) so that I am only using the `.map()` function, and get the same error result. The only places I can see that the error can be is in the `load_image()` function above, or in calling code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( ( images, labels ) )   # tf.constant() does not change error
dataset = dataset.map( load_map )
model.fit( dataset, epochs=100 )
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: Did you try using `Image generator` and the `flow_from_directory` function from Keras? It does a lot of things in a small function and is perfect for newbies. If you have an error, please update your question....

Comment: Can you try `set_shape` on the image tensor? I.e. In the `load_image` function, do `image.set_shape(image_shape)` (do this before return, the function itself is in place!!). The problem could be that TF doesn't "know" what the image will look like when it's loaded, so you have to tell it explicitly.

Comment: It seems most of the problem lies with `load_image` - see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14226

Comment: @neelg My image list is assembled from multiple labelled folders. I'd like to understand the program flow from simple python lists through to model.fit() via dataset in TF2.0+. It really shouldn't be so obscure or hard!

Comment: @omatai As I indicated before, the `image generator` function is perfect for you. But to use it you have to stick to a certain folder structure. You can plop images of cars in a folder named `cars` and the function will determine that all those pictures are of cars and feed them in the proper way. Thus it is extremely easy for using multiple folders...

Comment: I cannot stick to the certain folder structure: my data is complicated - sometimes I need to group classes of cars+vans+trucks into a super-group of vehicles :-( I think my problems are two-fold: that I was using decode_image() (does not set shape) instead of decode_jpeg(), and trying to use `car`, `van`, etc directly as labels... instead of 0, 1, 2... or a one-hot representation. Still working on it...

Comment: Well the function supports all these things (keep in mind that it is *specifically* made for this only) and only uses Keras. But in the end the choice is yours...{https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjBre_IoY_pAhX1ILcAHfUTCh8QFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmachinelearningmastery.com%2Fhow-to-load-large-datasets-from-directories-for-deep-learning-with-keras%2F&usg=AOvVaw3qieWZg4TQhfH1iOhdkotK}

Comment: I cannot see that the `image_generator` can handle combination classes where `cats`, `dogs`, `pigs` co-exist alongside `rats`, `mice`, `squirrels`... but the last three need to be bundled as `rodents` on some occasions, and not bundled on others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known problem with `decode_image` - it does not set shape information correctly (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14226). You can use a more specific call - e.g. `decode_jpeg` or `decode_png`.

Also... the next problem you will encounter is that you cannot directly use labels like "Tiger". If "Tiger" is in a list of categories like ["Lion", "Tiger", "Zebra", "Ape",...] then you either need to use the index of "Tiger" in such a list (i.e. `1`) or a one-hot representation (i.e. `[False,True,False,False,...]`)

Answer (score -1):

Please check this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) for information!

You can build the csv file first with the labels in the end column and pixel as the features. Then go through like this:

```
titanic_csv_ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    titanic_file_path,
    batch_size=5, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
    label_name='survived',
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=True,)
```